# TypeError: on_change_month_wage() takes at most 6 arguments (7 given)

Tags: function, onchange, openerp-7

I am developing a payroll module adapted to Venezuelan law and I'm creating a function that seeks the daily wage of an employee, all that came out well, the module makes the calculation, but; when I want to save the log I get this error:

> TypeError: on_change_month_wage() Takes at most six arguments (7 Given)

This is my code:

```
def on_change_month_wage(self, cr, uid, ids, month_wage, context=None):
    res = {}
    if month_wage > 0:
        res['diary_wage'] = month_wage / 30
    return {'value': res}

_columns = {
    'month_wage':fields.float('Salario Mensual', digits=(16,2)),
    'diary_wage':fields.function(on_change_month_wage, type = 'float', string = 'Salario Diario'),
}
```

and my xml lines:

```
<field name="month_wage" string="Salario Mensual" on_change="on_change_month_wage(month_wage)" />
<field name="diary_wage" string="Salario Diario" />
```

What should I do to solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not adviceable to use onchange method as function because on_chnage takes different argument for example:

**function**: This Function is return float because it's definition says `type = 'float'`

```
def cal_month_wage(self,cr,uid,ids,field_name,arg,context=None):
    ...
    ... #here your code logic

return float_value


'diary_wage':fields.function(cal_month_wage, type = 'float', string = 'Salario Diario')
```

**onchange**: Onchange return dictionary (key:value)

```
def on_change_month_wage(self, cr, uid, ids, month_wage, context=None):
    ...
    ... #here your code logic

return dictionary 

field name="month_wage" string="Salario Mensual" on_change="on_change_month_wage(month_wage)"
```

Hope you get basic different on onchnage and function. After than your problem will solved.